# How to download data from stocktwits?

Tags: python, stocktwits

It is my aim to download tweets from stocktwits via Python.

I found [this script](https://github.com/hamx0r/stocktwits/blob/master/api.py)  by Jason Haury. Sadly, I don't manage to get it run. What I did so far was download the "api.py" and the "requestors.py" scripts and replaced in the latter 'ST_ACCESS_TOKEN' with my access token. When I run the command `get_watched_stocks(my_watchlist_id)`, however, I get the following error:

```
ipython-input-12-b889976b3838> in get_watched_stocks(wl_id)
    115     """ Get list of symbols being watched by specified StockTwits watchlist
    116     """
--> 117     wl = R.get_json(ST_BASE_URL + 'watchlists/show/{}.json'.format(wl_id), params=ST_BASE_PARAMS)
    118     wl = wl['watchlist']['symbols']
    119     return [s['symbol'] for s in wl]
TypeError: unbound method get_json() must be called with Requests instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Does someone know what I might be doing wrong?
If not: could someone please give a step by step explanation on how I could use Mr. Haury's or any other script to download tweets from stocktwits?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use selenium, my script is for CC_transcript but you can apply it for any account of stocktwits :

```
###########################################################################
###  This script is a web scraper for stocktwits.                       ###
##   applied specifically on cc_transcripts   .                         ###
###  To use it you need first to install Python 3.5.2 on your computer. ###
###  Install the module "Selenium" 3.1.1, and "chromedriver.exe"        ###
###########################################################################


from selenium import webdriver
import sys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#only for Chrome, for firefox need another driver
print("Loading... Please wait")
Pathwebdriver="D:\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\Scripts\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(Pathwebdriver)
#website to analyse
driver.get("https://stocktwits.com/cctranscripts?q=cctranscripts")


#Scrolling of the webpage
ScrollNumber=3
print(str(ScrollNumber)+ " scrolldown will be done.")
for i in range(1,ScrollNumber):  #scroll down X times
    print("Scrolling... #"+str(i))
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2) #Delay between 2 scrolls down to be sure the page loaded, 1s is too short some loading take longer


#retrieving source code     
html_source = driver.page_source
data = str(html_source.encode('utf-8'))
#driver.close()#close of chrome to able the opwning of new windows and to save source code.

#Saving source code (in the same folder as this script)
SaveSource = False
if SaveSource:
    text_file = open("SourceCode.html", "w")
    text_file.write(data)
    text_file.close()


#Analysis of the source code
PosScanning=1
GlobalList=[]
print("Processing data")
while data[PosScanning:].find("picked")>0:

    PosPick=data[PosScanning:].find("picked") +PosScanning
    List = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] #Ticker,Nb of shares, Text of stocktwits,Link,Price of buying, Date, Text of CC_transcript

    #Quote
    dataBis=data[PosPick::-1] #reading the string backward
    PosBegin=PosPick - dataBis.find(">") +1 #looking for the begining of the text
    data=data[PosBegin:] #shortening the string each loop to increase the speed of processing
    PosEnd=data.find("<")#looking for the end of the text
    #print(data[PosBegin:PosEnd])
    List[2]=data[:PosEnd].replace(","," ")

    #Nb of shares
    List[1]=List[2].split(' up', 1 )[1]
    List[1]=List[1].split('share', 1 )[0]
    List[1]=List[1].replace(" ","")

    #link to the transcript
    PosLinkBegin=data.find("href=")+6
    PosLinkend=data.find("\"",PosLinkBegin,PosLinkBegin+3000)
    #print(data[PosLinkBegin:PosLinkend])
    List[3]=data[PosLinkBegin:PosLinkend]

    #Symbol
    PosSymbolBegin=data.find("data-symbol=")+13
    PosSymbolEnd=data.find("\"",PosSymbolBegin,PosSymbolBegin+300)
    #print(data[PosSymbolBegin:PosSymbolEnd])
    List[0]=data[PosSymbolBegin:PosSymbolEnd]

    #data-body, the "picked" is repeat 2 times, need to ignore it
    PosBody1=data.find("picked",PosSymbolEnd,PosSymbolEnd+10000)+100
    PosBody2=data.find("picked",PosBody1,PosBody1+10000)

    PosScanning=PosBody2 +100   
    GlobalList.append(List) 



#Opening Link to retrieve information
print("Opning links to retrieve detailed information form CC_transcript")
j=1
for item in GlobalList:
    print("Retrieving data: " +str(j)+"/"+str(len(GlobalList)))
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')#open tab
    driver.get(item[3]) 
    html_source2 = driver.page_source
    data2 = str(html_source2.encode('utf-8'))
    #text of CC_transcript
    TextePos=data2.find("$(\"#meaning\").popover();")
    item[6] = data2[TextePos+40:TextePos+1000].replace(","," ")  
    #price of Shares
    BuyPos=item[6].find("place at")+10
    BuyPosend=item[6][BuyPos:].find("share")+BuyPos +6
    item[4]=item[6][BuyPos:BuyPosend]  
    #date
    DatePos=item[6].find(" on ")
    DatePosEnd=item[6][DatePos:].find(".")+DatePos
    item[5]=item[6][DatePos+4:DatePosEnd] 
    j=j+1
driver.close()  

#output of final data   
print("Writting data in .csv file")
f = open('stocktwits.csv','w')
f.write("Ticker")
f.write(' , ')
f.write("Nb of shares")
f.write(' , ')
f.write("Text of stocktwits")
f.write(' , ')
f.write("Link")
f.write(' , ')
f.write("Price of buying")
f.write(' , ')
f.write("Date")
f.write(' , ')
f.write("Text of CC_transcript")
f.write('\n')
for item in GlobalList:
    for elem in item:
        f.write(elem)
        f.write(' , ')# excel change of column
    f.write('\n')   # excel change of line
f.close()

time.sleep(5)   
print("Done")
```

Answer (score 1):

@annach have a look at [pytwits](https://gitlab.com/stockpirates/public-projects/pytwits), a Python Wrapper for StockTwits' REST-API.

Since the project is very young, it is far from perfect, but to get a list of symbols on a watchlist you simply would do:

`pip install pytwits`

and then:

```
import pytwits


def main():

    access_token = 'TOKEN'
    stocktwits = pytwits.StockTwits(access_token=access_token)

    watchlist = stocktwits.watchlists(path='show', id='WL_ID_HERE')
    print('\n\n'.join([symbol['symbol'] for symbol in watchlist.symbols]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Taken from an [watchlist-example](https://gitlab.com/stockpirates/public-projects/pytwits/blob/master/docs/examples/show_watchlist.py) in the [examples-folder](https://gitlab.com/stockpirates/public-projects/pytwits/tree/master/docs/examples).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Requests class that was created in requestors.py, it looks like the creator wanted them to be static methods on the class but forgot to actually make them static methods. If you go into that file and put a `@staticmethod` above both function definitions it will work. For example

`def get_json(url, params=None):`

now becomes

`@staticmethod
def get_json(url, params=None):`

Tested and confirmed

Comment: Hey Eric, thanks for your answer!
I changed the code in "api.py" to 
"wl = R().get_json(ST_BASE_URL + 'watchlists/show/{}.json'.format(wl_id), params=ST_BASE_PARAMS)"

but now I get following error message:
TypeError: "get_json() got multiple values for keyword argument 'params' "

Don't really know how to deal with this :/

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect a simpler change to the code in order to make it work as designed.